# Is it possible to get $pwd value from Bazel .bzl rule?

Tags: bazel

I am trying to get a value of the full current directory path from within .bzl rule. I have tried following:

1. `ctx.host_configuration.default_shell_env.PATH` returns `"/Users/[user_name]/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:...`
2. `ctx.bin_dir.path` returns `bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin`
3. `pwd = ctx.expand_make_variables("cmd", "$$PWD", {})` returns string `$PWD` - I don't think this rule is helpful for me, but may be just using it wrong.

What I need is the directory under which the cmd that runs Bazel .bzl rule is running. For example: `/Users/[user_name]/git/workspace/path/to/bazel/rule.bzl` or at least first part of the path prior to the WORKSPACE directory.

I can't use `pwd` because I need this value before I call `ctx.actions.run_shell()`

Are there no attributes in Bazel configurations that hold this value?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bazel-discuss/PbCx8wZ4UkM

Answer (score 4):

The goal is to have hermetic builds, so you shouldn't depend on the absolute path.

Feel free to use `pwd` inside the command of `ctx.actions.run_shell()` (for reproducible builds, be careful, avoid putting the absolute path in the generated files).

---

**Edit.**
Technically, there are some workarounds. For example, you can pass the path via the `--define` flag:

```
bazel build :all --define=path=$(pwd)
```

Then the value will be available using `ctx.var["path"]`.

---

Based on your comment below, you want the path to declare an output. Let me repeat: You shouldn't use an absolute path to declare the output file. Declare an output in your package. Then ask the tool you call to use that output.

For example, when you call gcc, you can use `-o` to specify the output. When a tool writes to stdout, use the shell to redirect it. If the tool is really not flexible, you may want to wrap it with your own script (e.g. call the tool and copy the output file).

Using an absolute path here is not the right solution. For example, it should be possible to execute the action on a remote machine (where your absolute path won't make sense.

Zip may be a reasonable solution. It's useful when you cannot know in advance the number or the names of the output files.

Comment: I needed the `pwd` before I call `run_shell()` in order to declare output file coming from `coverage` command for python (Coverage.py utility names the source files for html report using absolute path). Instead of declaring output files explicitly I decided to just zip them up (better solution to my problem in general). I can accept your answer if you confirm that there is not way do get absolute path into bazel variable outside of `run_shell()`.

Comment: Thanks again, although my intension wasn't to declare the output in the absolute path location. What I am saying is that Coverage.py tool takes absolute path, switches the `/` with `_`, and uses that as a name of the html file it generates. So everything is still hermetic, I just want to know the name of the output file.